# How do I create a MultiIndex Dataframe from a merged table?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I am trying to run analysis on a merged dataframe.  Currently, my data is something like this:

```
data2 = pd.DataFrame({'county':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
                    '1990pop': [100, 200, 150, 400],
                     '1990price': [35, 20, 10, 60],
                     '1991pop': [110, 210, 160, 410],
                     '1991price': [7, 9, 8, 15]})
data2.set_index('county')
```

I want to create a MultiIndex so for for each row, you see the county, and then each county has an entry for a 'population' and a 'price' variable, and only one column for each for each year 1990 and 1991.

[Here's what I'd like the dataframe to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oV8HB.png)

I've tried various merging and MultiIndex guides but this is a bit beyond my ability. I'd greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Could you post how your desired DataFrame would look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since years are safely 4 digits, I would create a MultiIndex on the columns, then `stack`:

```
data2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([data2.columns.str[0:4], data2.columns.str[4:]],
                                          names=[None, 'Type'])
data2.stack(1)

              1990  1991
county Type             
A      pop     100   110
       price    35     7
B      pop     200   210
       price    20     9
C      pop     150   160
       price    10     8
D      pop     400   410
       price    60    15
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you need ? `wide_to_long` + `unstack` + `stack`

```
yourdf=pd.wide_to_long(data2,['1990','1991'],i=['county'],j='year',suffix='\w+').unstack().stack(1)
yourdf
Out[57]: 
              1990  1991
county year             
A      pop     100   110
       price    35     7
B      pop     200   210
       price    20     9
C      pop     150   160
       price    10     8
D      pop     400   410
       price    60    15
```

Answer (score 2):

#### `columns.str.extract` with `regex`

```
data2.set_axis(
    [*data2.columns.str.extract('(\d{4})(.*)').values.T],
    1, inplace=False
).stack().rename_axis(['country', 'type'])

               1990  1991
country type             
A       pop     100   110
        price    35     7
B       pop     200   210
        price    20     9
C       pop     150   160
        price    10     8
D       pop     400   410
        price    60    15
```